# My code is hanging when I call a function from another .py file

Tags: python-3.x, function, object, importerror

I know this code isn't all PEP8 compiant yet, but I'm working on getting it there. This program worked before I began refactoring it, but I've run into a problem I don't understand. Somehow I've messed up the import of Select.Die.py so that I get this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'user_input2' from 'Die_Generator'`. I'm not sure why, or how to fix it. I thought it might have to do with the objects being inside a while loop? At any rate, I'm really confused by this. If anyone could explain my problem I would appreciate it.

```
import Select_Die as sd
import Select_Quantity as sq
import Calculation

while True:
    user_input1 = input('Select die to roll: ').upper()
    print("check1")
    sd.die_selector()
    print("check2")
    # Choose your dice quantity
    user_input2 = input('Select die quantity to roll: ').upper()
    print("check3")
    sq.quantity_selector()
    print("check4")
    # Calculate your roll(s)
    Calculation.function()
```

The Select_Die code is:

```
import Data
from Die_Generator import user_input1 as input

def die_selector():
    if input == 'QUIT':
        exit()
    elif input == 'CONTROLS':
        print(Data.controls)
    try:
        if input in Data.Die_Names:
            print('Input accepted.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please select a valid dice. Only the dice listed above are accepted.')
    return input
```

Comment: You should wrap everything in the first file in a function and call that function from the second file. Even if what you had here worked, it wouldn't be a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your code is not hanging, but awaiting input. You are getting this input error because `user_input2` has not been defined at the time when you are trying to initialize `Select_Die`, but `Select_Die` tries to import it anyway. As a rule of thumb, you should not import non-static variables - you should pass them in as parameters instead.

Additionally, you never store the value returned from `die_selector()` or `quantity_selector()`, which I suspect is because you import it directly to `Calculation`.

You haven't shared `Data` or `Calculation` with us, but I assume you are importing the variables there as well. You should follow this same approach and rewrite `sq.quantity_selector()` to take `user_input2` as a parameter.

Side note: you should avoid using reserved words as variables names - in this case, that is `import`.

Here is your code with the above changes - except to `Calculation` and `Data`

```
import Select_Die as sd
import Select_Quantity as sq
import Calculation

while True:
    user_input1 = input('Select die to roll: ').upper()
    print("check1")
    selected_die = sd.die_selector(user_input1)
    print("check2")
    # Choose your dice quantity
    user_input2 = input('Select die quantity to roll: ').upper()
    print("check3")
    selected_quantity = sq.quantity_selector()
    print("check4")
    # Calculate your roll(s)
    Calculation.function(selected_die, selected_quantity)
```

```
import Data

def die_selector(inp):
    if inp == 'QUIT':
        exit()
    elif inp == 'CONTROLS':
        print(Data.controls)
    try:
        if inp in Data.Die_Names:
            print('Input accepted.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please select a valid dice. Only the dice listed above are accepted.')
    return inp
```